# How to access a modelform's Foreignkey attribute from within a template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms

### Description:

I would like to know how to access a ForeignKey's field within template code.

Given the sample models.py code:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
```

And Sample forms.py code:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Book
         fields = ['title', 'publisher']
```

And sample views.py code:

```
def sample(request):
  bf = BookForm(request.POST)
  return render(request, 'sample.html', {'BookForm': bf})
```

### Question:

What is line(s) of code needed to correctly access the value: **publisher.name** from within template code using 'BookForm'?

Comment: So you want to access the foreign key field from a form object ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been able to use `{{ BookForm.instance.publisher.name }}` to display foreign field values. This works only to display the current instance.

Comment: Seems like a great way, but ultimately it did not work when I tried

Comment: Ah.. I was mistaken.. Works like a charm - Thanks

Comment: Is it mandatory to pass the instance ? 
bf = BookForm(instance = "book_instance")

Comment: @KiranRuthR, I did not understand your question. Are you asking whether it is necessary to pass the instance to the template as in `return render(request, 'sample.html', {'BookForm': bf})`? Yes you have to.